# Inverse of $5$ under multiplication modulo $11$ on $Z_{11}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find the inverse of $5$ under multiplication modulo $11$ on $Z_{11}$

Please help me with problem. Can't show any work because I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You're looking for a number $n$ such that $5n \equiv 1 (\mod{11})$.

Answer (score 2):

You have $11=5\times 2+1$, so $-2\times 5=1 \pmod{11}$.
So the inverse of $5$ in $Z_{11}$ is $-2=9 \pmod{11}$.

Comment: Nice trick. Better than my "$11,22,33,44,$ aha! $45/5=9$"

Answer (score 0):

if you know fermat's little theorem $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p $.

Then you can use this fact since $$a^{p-2} \cdot a = a \cdot a^{p-2} \equiv 1 \mod p$$

so just calculate $a^{p-2} \mod p$

in your case $5^9 \mod 11 = 9$